# Why is Boston not defined? How do I read names from files?

Tags: python

My code:

```
infile = open("pa6numbers.py","r")
num = eval(infile.readline())

Boston = infile
sum = 0
infant = 0
elder = 0
pneumonia = 0

while num != -1:

 if num != -1:
     sum +=int(num)
 elif num < 1:
     infant=+1
 elif num > 65:
     elder += 1
 else:
     pneumonia+=1
 num = eval(infile.realine())

infile.close()
```

This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Stephen/Desktop/Python/pa6.py", line 15, in <module>
    num = eval(infile.readline())
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Boston' is not defined
```

When I run my program it tells me 'NameError: name 'Boston' is not defined'. In the file that I am reading from there are states and my assignment is to print out the states and the rates of infant, elder and pnemonia deaths. So I would like to know how I would read names from the file.

Please do not go too complex due to the fact I'm on in a CMPS 150 and the professor does not want us to go ahead of the class.

Part of the beginning of the file I am reading from:

```
Boston, MA
509953
41145
20577
309257
Bridgeport, CT
113119
8921
2546
78218
```

Comment: With the code you provided, you **can't** get the NameError. Please provide the full relevant code and the full traceback, including line numbers!

Comment: "_Why is Boston not defined?_"

Comment: Why are you doing `eval(infile.readline())`? It is highly unlikely that the lines of the file are arbitrary Python expressions you want to evaluate; for example, it sounds like the first line of the file is `Boston`, or starts with `Boston`.

Comment: @linusg: You can, from the `eval`s.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As-is, your question is hard to answer. You should at least provide (part of) the input file and the required output. Look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The file that i am reading from starts with Boston

Comment: @StephenEric Question seems to be unclear, I guess you should read the file. As per my understanding, change Boston = infile.read()

Comment: `eval()` is for executing valid Python expressions contained in strings—something you generally wouldn't want to do with data being read from an external text file and in this case the file doesn't contain expressions. You need to read the lines of the file in groups of 5, and process each one. It's very unclear from your code ***what** exactly you're trying to do with things like the if `num < 1` and `num > 65` checks. You need to pay more attention in class, so you'll have some clue as to how to do the homework.

Answer (score 2):

By using `eval`, you are assuming that the contents of the data file are valid Python, *which they are not*.

Watch what happens if we try to evaluate the first line in an interactive Python session:

```
> python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Dec 28 2016, 20:51:25) 
>>> eval('Boston, MA')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Boston' is not defined
```

What you could do to `read()` the data into a string and then use the `splitlines()` method of that string. Based on the fragment of the input file you've shown, you would then get a list of strings like this. (The examples below are pasted from an interactive Python environment called IPython, check it out.)

```
In [3]: lines
Out[3]: 
['Boston, MA',
 '509953',
 '41145',
 '20577',
 '309257',
 'Bridgeport, CT',
 '113119',
 '8921',
 '2546',
 '78218']
```

You could convert that to a usable data structure with a *dictionary comprehension* like this:

```
In [7]: {lines[j]: tuple(int(lines[i]) for i in range(j+1, j+5)) for j in range(0, len(lines), 5)}
Out[7]: 
{'Boston, MA': (509953, 41145, 20577, 309257),
 'Bridgeport, CT': {113119, 8921, 2546, 78218)}
```

This *comprehension* is equivalent to the following nested `for`-loop:

```
In [9]: data = {}
   ...: for j in range(0, len(lines), 5):
   ...:     numbers = []
   ...:     for i in range(j+1, j+5):
   ...:         numbers.append(int(lines[i]))
   ...:     data[lines[j]] = tuple(numbers)
   ...:     

In [10]: data
Out[10]: 
{'Boston, MA': (509953, 41145, 20577, 309257),
 'Bridgeport, CT': (113119, 8921, 2546, 78218)}
```

You can now index this data by city:

```
In [11]: data['Boston, MA']
Out[11]: (509953, 41145, 20577, 309257)
```

or iterate over the keys and values:

```
In [16]: for k, v in data.items():
    ...:     print('key =',k, '; values =', v)
    ...:     
key = Boston, MA ; values = (509953, 41145, 20577, 309257)
key = Bridgeport, CT ; values = (113119, 8921, 2546, 78218)
```

Comment: Note that `readlines` keeps the line terminators, unlike your `lines` list. Ordinarily, I'd recommend iterating over the file directly instead of using `readlines`, but it's tricky to convert the indexing, and you're building a complete in-memory representation of the data anyway.

Comment: (Iterating over the file directly also keeps newlines; it's not intended to "fix" that.)

Comment: Uh... am I supposed to be seeing an edit? You may have forgotten to hit "Save Edits".

Comment: @user2357112 accidentally killed my browser. :-/

Answer (score 0):

This question is impossible to answer in it's current state. I have copied your code, and read your comments. I have included on the first line in the pa6numbers.py file the word "Boston". Your error was replicated on my system, but it is not referencing Boston in your pa6.py file as not being defined, but the Boston in your pa6numbers.py file not being defined. If you want to parse this file, you need to make it plain txt. Not a PY file. That is one mistake I am seeing among others atm. It is expecting Boston in your pa6numbers.py file to be a variable, but it is not defined as such as I can tell based on the context clues that I have gathered. Without having your actual file this is the best educated guess anyone can make at this point. I have a feeling that I am probably correct in assuming this is how the file is set up.

Now with that said, you also have a typo on line 20 of you pa6.py file.

```
num = eval(infile.realine())
```

This should read

```
num = eval(infile.readline())
```

you have realine. Please post the file you are parsing and make it plain text and we can give you a better answer.